# How to change carousel image slider arrows color only on the second slide?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

how can i change the carousel image slider indicator arrows color only on the second image slide???
On the first slide i want to be black color, but when the image slide to 2nd slide i want to set the indicators to white color.
Is this possible???
I tried to create id tag on second slide, but its not helped, someone who is expert in CSS know how to do this???
The big problem is i can't target in CSS only the second slide carousel icons, and i don't know how to do this.

And i want to target the second image slider arrow icon in CSS to set the arrow color to white.
carousel-control-next, .carousel-control-prev

Here is the HTML code,this is the Carousel image slider sample:

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>


  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="1.jpg"   alt="First slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h2 id="fadeuptext" class='animated fadeInUp' style="animation-delay: 1s">Hello</h2>
      <h2 id="fadelefttext" class='animated fadeInLeft' style="animation-delay: 2s">World</h2>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="2.jpg" style="height:797px;"   alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="3.jpg" style="height:797px;"   alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>


  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need to do this because you can't see the indicators on the second slide?

Comment: Yes,the picture what i use too much dark,and the arrow indicators is on black color.So i want to change to white color.

Comment: Could you edit the image so they display on both light and dark backgrounds? eg add some shadow/glow to reveal the outline?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do some javascript, first attatch an id to the element you want to modify, then control in which slide you are at to modify the class of saved element.